# Gnuplot histogram with Matlab style

Tags: matlab, plot, gnuplot

I want to plot a 3D histogram with Gnuplot using a style commonly used in Matlab.
The sequence of steps I follow are:

```
set palette defined ( 0 '#000090',\
                      1 '#000fff',\
                      2 '#0090ff',\
                      3 '#0fffee',\
                      4 '#90ff70',\
                      5 '#ffee00',\
                      6 '#ff7000',\
                      7 '#ee0000',\
                      8 '#7f0000')

set pm3d at s
set view map 
splot 'test.dat' u 1:2:3
```

The data to make the plot is provided below. The resulting plot looks like this:
[image]

As you may see in the data below, most of the entries are zero which makes the plot very blue. In Matlab one can make this type of histograms and zero values have a white color. Just the points which are not zero have a color as in the palette above. I would like to have those points in white because that would emphasize the actual sampled region.

I wonder if we can do that in Gnuplot. I tried omitting the zeroes in the data file but it resulted in a pointy-corners plot.

Additionally, I modified the palette defining the zero value explicitly as here:

```
set palette defined ( 0 '#ffffff',\
                      1 '#000090',\
                      2 '#000fff',\
                      3 '#0090ff',\
                      4 '#0fffee',\
                      5 '#90ff70',\
                      6 '#ffee00',\
                      7 '#ff7000',\
                      8 '#ee0000',\
                      9 '#7f0000')
```

However, the borders of the sampled area look color violet:

[image]

Thanks.

```
   1           1           1
   1           2           0
   1           3           0
   1           4           0
   1           5           0
   1           6           0
   1           7           0
   1           8           0

   2           1           0
   2           2           0
   2           3           1
   2           4           2
   2           5           3
   2           6           0
   2           7           0
   2           8           0

   3           1           0
   3           2           0
   3           3           2
   3           4          10
   3           5          15
   3           6           2
   3           7           0
   3           8           0

   4           1           0
   4           2           0
   4           3           0
   4           4           5
   4           5           2
   4           6           1
   4           7           0
   4           8           0

   5           1           0
   5           2           0
   5           3           0
   5           4           3
   5           5           2
   5           6           0
   5           7           0
   5           8           0

   6           1           0
   6           2           0
   6           3           0
   6           4           2
   6           5           0
   6           6           0
   6           7           1
   6           8           0

   7           1           0
   7           2           0
   7           3           0
   7           4           0
   7           5           0
   7           6           0
   7           7           0
   7           8           0

   8           1           0
   8           2           0
   8           3           0
   8           4           0
   8           5           0
   8           6           0
   8           7           0
   8           8           0
```

Comment: Did you try setting the corresponding palette entry to white?

Comment: I tried setting the value of zero to #ffffff (white color), but the resulting plot looks odd at the borders. They look darker than the neighboring points.

Comment: I don't know what that means. Do note that you have an 8x8 array, but are creating only 7x7 squares. The data is at the intersections. This might be a reason why the resulting plot looks odd at the borders.

Comment: Please, see the information I just added to the initial question.

Comment: It looks to me that the grid is drawn in one color, and the border in a different color. If you look carefully, you can observe the same in the original plot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plotting with `pm3d` averages the data points. If you want to plot exactly the data points as matrix, you must `plot with image`. To have certain values in white, define them as undefined with `1/0`:

```
set palette defined ( 0 '#000090',\
                      1 '#000fff',\
                      2 '#0090ff',\
                      3 '#0fffee',\
                      4 '#90ff70',\
                      5 '#ffee00',\
                      6 '#ff7000',\
                      7 '#ee0000',\
                      8 '#7f0000')

plot 'test.dat' u 1:2:($3 == 0 ? 1/0 : $3) with image notitle
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

I just saw the answer above using `image` (I'll upvote that one), and that is probably the best way to accomplish what you asked for. In any case, I made a few tests with the data file and wanted to share just for completeness:

```
set term png
set out "tmp.png"

set palette defined ( 0 '#ffffff',\
                      1 '#000090',\
                      2 '#000fff',\
                      3 '#0090ff',\
                      4 '#0fffee',\
                      5 '#90ff70',\
                      6 '#ffee00',\
                      7 '#ff7000',\
                      8 '#ee0000',\
                      9 '#7f0000')

set xrange[0:8]
set yrange[0:8]

set pm3d explicit at s
set view map 

set multiplot layout 2,2

splot 'test.dat' u 1:2:3 not w pm3d
splot 'test.dat' u 1:2:3 not w p pt 5 ps 5 pal
splot 'test.dat' u 1:2:($3==0 ? 1/0:$3) not w pm3d
```

Resulting in this:

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks. Hi, this is the plot I am getting but I want to improve. I would like somehow make all zero entries white and all the other points to make use of the palette I mentioned above (without 0 '#ffffff'). I am trying to avoid the blurred region between 0 and 2 (as shown in the scale box in your plot).